# Snakemake use all samples as one input with porechop

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm trying to use porechop on several data with a Snakemake workflow.

In my Snakefile, there are three rules, a fastqc rule and a porechop rule, in addition to the all rule. The fastqc rule works very well, I have all three out for my three fastq. But for porechop, instead of running the command three times, it runs the command once with the -i flag for all three files at the same time:

```
Error in rule porechop:
    jobid: 2
    output: /ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/prod/porechop/25022021_2_pore.fastq.gz, /ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/prod/porechop/02062021_1_pore.fastq.gz, /ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/prod/porechop/02062021_2_pore.fastq.gz
    conda-env: /ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/.snakemake/conda/a72fb141b37718b7c37d9f32d597faeb
    shell:
        porechop -i /ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/reads/25022021_2.fastq.gz /ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/reads/02062021_1.fastq.gz /ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/reads/02062021_2.fastq.gz -o /ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/prod/porechop/25022021_2_pore.fastq.gz /ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/prod/porechop/02062021_1_pore.fastq.gz /ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/prod/porechop/02062021_2_pore.fastq.gz -t 40 --discard_middle
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
```

However, when I use it with a single sample, the program works.

Here my code:

```
import glob
import os

###Global Variables###

FORMATS=["zip", "html"]
DIR_FASTQ="/ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/reads"

###FASTQ Files###

def list_samples(DIR_FASTQ):
        SAMPLES=[]
        for file in glob.glob(DIR_FASTQ+"/*.fastq.gz"):
                base=os.path.basename(file)
                sample=(base.replace('.fastq.gz', ''))
                SAMPLES.append(sample)
        return(SAMPLES)

SAMPLES=list_samples(DIR_FASTQ)

###Rules###
rule all:
        input:
                expand("/ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/stats/fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.{ext}", sample=SAMPLES, ext=FORMATS),
                expand("/ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/prod/porechop/{sample}_pore.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES)
rule fastqc:
        input:
                expand(DIR_FASTQ+"/{sample}.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES)
        output:
                expand("/ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/stats/fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.{ext}", sample=SAMPLES, ext=FORMATS)
        threads:
                16
        conda:
                "envs/fastqc.yaml"
        shell:
                "fastqc {input} -o /ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/stats/fastqc/ -t {threads}"

rule porechop:
        input:
                expand(DIR_FASTQ+"/{sample}.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES)
        output:
                expand("/ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/prod/porechop/{sample}_pore.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES)
        threads:
                40
        conda:
                "envs/porechop.yaml"
        shell:
                "porechop -i {input} -o {output} -t {threads} --discard_middle"
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question comes up often... If you use `expand()` in `input:` or `output:` then you are feeding the rule with a list of all the files. That is the same as writing:

```
input:
    ['sample1.fastq', 'sample2.fastq', ..., 'sampleN.fastq'],
output:
    ['sample1.pore.fastq', 'sample2.pore.fastq', ..., 'sampleN.pore.fastq'],
```

To run the rule on each input/output just remove the expand:

```
rule porechop:
    input:
        DIR_FASTQ+"/{sample}.fastq.gz"
    output:               
        "/ngs/prod/nanocea_project/test/prod/porechop/{sample}_pore.fastq.gz",
```